# Android easiest way to set layout for orientation

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in manifest and create two xml activity_main(port) and layout(land) under res folder.I want to set it change between two layout when I rotate ,how to edit my code? Thanks
After I change twice the method under oncreate is not works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:paddingTop="5dp">
<TextView  android:id="@+id/tv" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"  android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:textSize="30dip"
android:textColor="#ff0000"></TextView>

<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dip">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/Button07"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/Button08"/><Button
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9"
    android:id="@+id/Button09"/><Button
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonJia"/>

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dip">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/Button04"></Button>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/Button05"></Button><Button
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/Button06"></Button><Button
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonJian"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/Button01"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/Button02"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/Button03"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCheng"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="c"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonC"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/Button00"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDengyu"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonChu"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView  android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip" android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"  android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/Button071"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/Button081"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/Button091"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonJia1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/Button041"></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/Button051"></Button><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/Button061"></Button><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonJian1"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/Button011"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/Button021"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/Button031"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCheng1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dip">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="c"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonC1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/Button001"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDengyu1"/><Button
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonChu1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need to create layout-land and layout-port folders inside your res directory and create layouts with the same names in each of this folders. For example you create activity_main.xml layout inside layout_land folder and different layout with the same name inside layout-port folder. And then call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in your activity

[image]

Comment: It seems not allow me to use the same name

Comment: @JasonWang you must create files with the same name in different folders. One activity_layout.xml in layout-land folder, second activity_layout.xml in layout-port folder. It is allowed to create files with the same name inside different directories

Comment: It merge to layout file automatically.Resource @layout/activity_main already exists

Comment: @JasonWang I've updated my answer with a screenshot. Please make sure, that you have this structure in your res folder. May be cleaning and rebuilding a project will help you?

Comment: OK I have success rename it,can you check my onConfigurationChanged method at the code below?After I rotated it the app was not work

Comment: @JasonWang you don't need this method since you have layout-land and layout-port directories. It will change layouts automatically, if you call setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in your onCreate() method. Also, it is very useful to read this article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: After I onConfigurationChanged method,it works.I think I do not need using that method

Comment: Can you always check my layout.xml ,how to set it to present a land layout? thanks

Comment: @JasonWang excuse me, but I've not understood you. Do you want to use this layout in landscape mode?

Comment: I have using tablelayout it success present landscape mode but when I change to port it not transfer to port.

Comment: https://github.com/EasonWang01/Calcutator    you can repo my project and edit it.

Comment: @JasonWang try to remove orientation from your configChanges in manifest file

Comment: After I remove orientation when I rotated it will relaunch app again.

Comment: @JasonWang it relaunches your activity. That is how android works - when you rotate screen it restarts your activity and automatically inflates layout that you need. If you don't want to restart the activity you need to handle screen change by yourself, but it is a bad practice, because you need to relaunch whole state of your activity by yourself (for example reinit all your views).

Comment: Most app will not relaunch after rotate it,can you using my code give me a simple example how to not relaunch?

Comment: Most of apps use fragments instead of activities for representing ui. Check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html . With activity you have to choose only between two ways, and way with recreating activity is the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle something in on orientation change just use follow overridden method in side your activity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```